# Replace one by one values of an array list and store the values of another array using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist

How to replace one by one values of an array list and store the values of another array using for loop?

As I want the user to write any line, then I want the code to eliminate all the numbers as well as symbol from the user input and convert the remaining user input into uppercase and then if I get something BDJH from the program I want the program to shift the value of alphabet by one therefore the answer should be or the output should be  CEKI as (earlier it was BDJH shifted by one in alphabetical order).

But my program is not running, I don't know the error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nanana {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("ENTER THE NUMBER YOU WANT ENCRYPTED");
        Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in);
        String name =input1.nextLine();
        encryption(name);
        name=name.toUpperCase();
        ArrayList<Character> nilkil =new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i=0;i<=name.length()-1;i++){
            nilkil.add(name.charAt(i)); 
        }
        char[] deep={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
        for(int j=0;j<=nilkil.size()-1;j++) {
            for (int p = 0; p <=deep.length-1; p++) {
                if(nilkil.get(j)==deep[p]){
                    nilkil.add(j,deep[p+1]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(nilkil.toString());
    }

    public static String encryption(String name){
        name=name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]" ,"");
        name=name.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(name);
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not running but you don't know the error? What happens? Does it crash? Not desired output?

Comment: when i am giving an input like asdd the console is returning simply ASDD but it should return BTEE ????

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting the input string to character array then increment each ASCII character by 1 as you required. One thing keep your class name meaningful and starts with Caps.

```
public class CharacterConversion{
     public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("ENTER THE NUMBER YOU WANT ENCRYPTED");
            Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in);
            String name =input1.nextLine();
            encryption(name);
            name=name.toUpperCase();

            char[] namesArray = name.toCharArray();

            for(int i=0;i<namesArray.length;i++){
              namesArray[i] = (char) (namesArray[i]+1);
            }
            System.out.println(new String(namesArray));
        }

        public static String encryption(String name){
            name=name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]" ,"");
            name=name.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(name);
            return name;
        }

}
```

Comment: With the input `a1b2c3` this outputs `B2C3D4`. (It doesn't remove the numbers as the OP wanted)

Answer (score 0):

Please find correct answer for your problem.

```
import java.util.*;

public class nanana {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("ENTER THE NUMBER YOU WANT ENCRYPTED");
        Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in);
        String name =input1.nextLine();
        name=encryption(name);
        ArrayList<Character> nilkil =new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i=0;i<=name.length()-1;i++){
            nilkil.add(name.charAt(i));
        }
        String answer="";
        char[] deep={'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
        for(int j=0;j<=nilkil.size()-1;j++) {
            if(nilkil.get(j)=='Z') //Replacing Z with A
                answer=answer+'A';
            else{
            for (int p = 0; p <deep.length-1; p++) {
                if (nilkil.get(j) == deep[p]) {
                    answer = answer + deep[p + 1];
                    break;
                }
            }


            }

        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }


    public  static String encryption(String name){
        name=name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]" ,"");
        name=name.toUpperCase();
        return name;
    }
}
```